# Sklearn transformer to ensure input variable length is consistent?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a sklearn pipeline that has a step which fractionally differentiates the features to ensure stationarity. If a feature needs to be made stationary - its length is reduced by 1. If it does not require fractional differentiation, its length remains the same (I think).

```
from fracdiff.sklearn import Fracdiff
...
self.clf = Pipeline(
                steps=[("preprocessor", self.preprocessor),
                       ("simple_imputer", simple_imputer),
                       ("fracdiff", Fracdiff()),
                       ("classifier", model)])
```

When I apply this pipeline step it results in:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1665, 1666]
```

I think a reasonable solution would be to standardize the input variable lengths after the `fracdiff` step to be `= min_length` of any one feature in X.

My questions:

1. Is this a reasonable assumption / approach?
2. Can you advise on how I would go about doing this in a sklearn pipeline step/transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using the wrong method from the fracdiff library.

`self.fracdiff_transformer = FracdiffStat()`

```
self.clf = Pipeline(
                steps=[("preprocessor", self.preprocessor),
                       ("simple_imputer", simple_imputer),
                       ("fracdiff", self.fracdiff_transformer),
                       ("classifier", model)])
```

This resolved the issue.